# Update a row in a table respecting a constraint on another table

Tags: postgresql, transactions, race-condition

```
book:
  id: primary key, integer
  title: varchar
  borrowed: boolean
  borrowed_by_user_id: foreign key user.id

user:
  id: primary key, integer
  name: varchar
  blocked: boolean
```

The isolation level is READ COMMITED, because it is default level in PostgreSQL (this requirement is not from me).

I am using one database transaction to `SELECT FOR UPDATE` a book and lend it to any user if book is not borrowed yet. The book was selected `FOR UPDATE` so it cannot be borrowed concurrently.

But there is another problem. We cannot allow to lend a book to blocked user. How can we ascertain that? Even if we check at the beginning if user is not blocked, the result might not be correct because a concurrent transaction could block the user *after* that check.

For example, a user can be blocked by a concurrent transaction from the admin's panel.

How to solve that issue?

---

1. I see that I can use `SERIALIZABLE`. It requires a handling errors, yes?
2. I am not sure how that `CHECK` works. Could you say more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are actually two questions.

**About the books:**

If you lock the book with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` as soon as you consider lending it out, this is an example of “pessimistic locking” and will block the book for all concurrent activity.

That is fine if the transactions are very short – specifically, if there is no user interaction between the locking and the end of the transaction.

Otherwise you should use “optimistic locking”. This can be done in several ways:

1. Use `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation. Then updating a book that has been modified since you read its data will lead to a serialization error (see the note at the end).
2. When selecting books, remember the values of the system columns `ctid` and `xmin`. Then update as follows:

   ```
   UPDATE books SET ...
   WHERE id = ...
     AND ctid = original_ctid AND xmin = original_xmin;
   ```

   If no row gets updated, somebody must have modified the book since you looked at it.

**About the users:**

Three ideas:

1. You use `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation (see the note at the end).
2. You maintain a counter on the user that contains the number of books the user has borrowed.

   Then you can have a check constraint like

   ```
   ALTER TABLE users ADD CHECK (NOT blocked OR books_borrowed = 0);
   ```

   Such a check constraint is evaluated at the end of each statement and has to yield `TRUE`, else an error is thrown.

   So either the transaction that borrows a book or the transaction that blocks the user must fail (both transactions have to modify the user).
3. Right before lending a book to a user, you run

   ```
   SELECT blocked FROM users WHERE id = ... FOR UPDATE;
   ```

   If you get TRUE, you abort the transaction, otherwise lend out the book.

   A concurrent transaction that wants to block the user has to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the user as well and *only then* check if there are any books lent to that user.

   That way, no inconsistency can happen: if you want to block a user, all concurrent transactions that want to lend a book to the user must either be completed, so that you see their effect, or they must wait until you are done blocking the user, whereupon they will fail.

**Note about higher isolation levels:**

If you run transactions at an isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`, you can encounter *serialization errors*. These are not bugs in your program, they are normal and to be expected. If you encounter a serialization error, you have to rollback and try the same transaction again. That is the price you pay for not having to worry about race conditions.

Comment: What about? `SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN user ON book.borrowed_by_user_id = user.id WHERE NOT user.blocked FOR UPDATE?

Comment: That will lock all users that are not blocked and all books lent out to such users, which is probably massive. What good should that do?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN user ON book.borrowed_by_user_id = user.id WHERE NOT user.blocked AND book.id = 100 FOR UPDATE`
Now, is it safe in the sense of my post?

Comment: That will lock a book and optionally the user who has borrowed it. It depends on the context if that makes sense. I thought locking a book is a problem for you; at least that is what your question suggests. Did you understand my answer?

Comment: Yes, I understand. Blocking a concrete book is not problem in my case. Example with book and user is a some of model my situation- but- in my model there is no problem with locking. I see also your point. It is a weak solution from point of view performance. And I edited my post. 

Thanks for your answer- it is really helpful. When I ask that question in other places I was answered that it is my imaginated problem :)

Comment: I added some more about transaction isolation and check constraints. You should read the PostgreSQL documentation on these subjects, it explains things better than I can.